# Is there any possibility to add multiple peers in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

Generally, we do not have peers concepts in Corda. We always call them as nodes. How to create multiple peers (nodes) for single organization (Party) in Corda?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can register as many peers (nodes) for the same organization. As long as, you let your counterparties know that those X509 names belong to your organization.

But, keep in mind that your peers cannot share from the database level, meaning that if peerA received some info from an external party and stored at its vault, PeerB cannot just go into peerA's vault and use it for its transactions.

That is, PeerA and PeerB are entirely different parties on the Corda level. If you want to share some information, you need to do a Flow. This is to protecting provenance and immutability of the ledger.

Looking into the future, our dev team is implementing a new accounts feature. It will be released with Corda Enterprise 5. This feature allows having multiple accounts under the same node. If you would like more information join the slack channel and ping me @http://slack.corda.net